# nasm assembly: string is printed twice

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have written following x86 assembly code for NASM assembler.

**hello.asm**

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bx, HELLO_MSG
call print_string

mov bx, GOODBYE_MSG
call print_string

jmp $

%include "print_string.asm"

HELLO_MSG:
    db 'hello, world',0

GOODBYE_MSG:
    db 'good bye',0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

**print_string.asm**

```
print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    push bx

    loop:
        cmp WORD [bx], 0
        je end
        mov al, [bx]
        int 0x10
        inc bx
        jmp loop

    end:
        pop bx
        ret
```

I have run the code in bochs 2.2.6 emulator.

**Expected outpur**

> hello worldgood bye

**output i am getting**

> hello world good byegood bye

Why `good bye` is printed twice? also notice there is an extra space after `hello, world`. Where it is coming from?
NB: If I print only one string code works just fine.

Comment: Your problem comes from `cmp WORD`.  If you are looking for `db 0`, that's just a byte, not a word, so it not finding the "end of string" until it hits the `times 510-($-$$) db 0`.

Comment: First I tried `cmp [bx], 0`. but assembler was reporting that it can't determine the size. Then I tried `mov dx, [bx]` then `cmp dx, 0`. But it was giving same erroneous output. Now I understand why! `cmp BYTE [bx], 0` is working.

Can you make it an answer? So that I can mark this as answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the line

```
cmp WORD [bx], 0
```

This is saying "compare the word at the address pointed to by bx with 0."  However, the string that you are looking at is made of bytes, not words.  In order for this compare to succeed, it would have to find 2 bytes in a row (aka a word) that both contain zeros.

This doesn't happen at the end of HELLO_MSG, so it just keeps printing characters, walking right thru the following string (GOODBYE_MSG), until it finally finds a pair at `times 510-($-$$) db 0`.

This also explains the extra space you are seeing, since you are actually printing the 0 at the end of HELLO_MSG.